# Sending url-encoded parameters in a superagent GET request

Tags: get, httprequest, url-parameters, supertest, superagent

With curl I can send GET-requests with url-encoded parameters as follows:

```
curl -G http://example.com --data-urlencode "key=val"
```

How do I do this with [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) / [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)? So far I've tried things like

```
const response = await request(app)
  .get('/')
  .type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  .send({ key: 'val' });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify `form` in `type` like below:

```
const response = await request(app)
  .get('/')
  .type('form') // change into `form`
  .send({ key: 'val' });
```

Ref:
https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of it this way:

```
const response = await request(app)
        .get('/')
        .send('key=val&key2=val2&key3=val3');
```

Documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest (Search 'x-www-form-urlencoded upload')